# Convert filed value in integer type in mongodb during aggregate

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb, int, aggregate

How can I convert string to int type in stage during aggregate in mongodb?

```
{ $lookup:{ from: 'circle', localField:'circle_id', foreignField: 'circle_id', as: 'circleDetail' } },
```

- localField: 'circle_id' -> int type
- foreignField: 'circle_id' -> string type

I want to convert foreign field into int type.

Comment: in which variable you are storing your 'circle_id'?

Comment: i didn't get what you are asking. BTW, I am joining 2 collection based on circle_id

Comment: use  foreignField:  +'circle_id' in your lookup This will convert your string to number.

Comment: I did but not wroked 
this is the error I am getting after add + before circle_id $lookup argument 

'foreignField: nan.0' must be a string, is type double

Comment: Why are they different type in the first place?

Comment: Hello Dijkstra
circle_id is different type from begining in SQL now migrating into mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$convert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) or [`$toInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) operator. This works from version 4.0 on.